# Simplifying string checking from array in NSPredicate

Tags: objective-c, ios, nspredicate

For a syncing service, I'm trying to cut down on loops as many as possible using predicates.

I currently have something like this:

```
for (NSString *filterOutPath in toFilterOutPaths) {
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (href CONTAINS %@)", filterOutPath];
    toUpdateFiles = [toUpdateFiles filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
}
```

I'm aiming for something more like this:

```
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (href CONTAINS (ANY IN %@))", toFilterOutPaths];
toUpdateFiles = [toUpdateFiles filteredArrayUsingPredicate:pred];
```

Any ideas?  Thank you so much for any and all contributions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, why do you want to eliminate the loop? Do you think it will run faster? If so, why? Running several simple predicates may be as fast as running one complex predicate.

Secondly, you can't combine CONTAINS, ANY and IN in the way you propose. Instead, you could create a compound predicate like this:

```
NSMutableArray *predicates = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:toFilterOutPaths.count];

for (NSString *filterOutPath in toFilterOutPaths) {
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (href CONTAINS %@)", filterOutPath];
    [predicates addObject:predicate];
}

NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicates];

toUpdateFiles = [toUpdateFiles filteredArrayUsingPredicate:compoundPredicate];
```

Comment: Thank you, I haven't even thought of a compound predicate.